# view duplicate data in sql statement

Tags: sql, view, duplicates

```
SELECT REPLACE( nokp,  '-',  '' ) AS kp, nama, COUNT( id ) 
FROM participants
GROUP BY kp
HAVING COUNT( * ) >1
```

this is my sql statement to find the duplicate data. but actually i want to view all data in that  row that have duplicate nokp. (SELECT *) and view data that have duplicate nokp.

EDIT..
I have done what exactly i want to view.

```
SELECT REPLACE( nokp,  '-',  '' ) AS kp1, nama, daerah, parlimen, dun, pbt, mukim, alamat, telefon, j_kerja
FROM participants
WHERE REPLACE( nokp,  '-',  '' ) 
IN (

SELECT REPLACE( nokp,  '-',  '' ) AS kp
FROM participants
GROUP BY kp
HAVING COUNT( * ) >1
)
ORDER BY  `kp1` ASC
```

Comment: Your requirements are contradictive. If you have multiple items with the same nokp, then there is a different data for each nokp, which of them do you want to see in your output?

Comment: @Guneli i want to view data from the same kp.

Comment: It seems I could not explain well. Let's assume you have 3 rows with nokp=1, for one of them nama is 1, for the second is 2, and for the last is 3? Which nama value should be in your output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select *
From participants
Where nokp in
(
  Select nokp
  From participants
  Group by nokp
  Having count(*) > 1
 )
```

This will give you the all the rows with duplicate values.